# which Perl ssh module support kerberos auth?

Tags: perl, ssh, kerberos, gssapi

My Linux server group uses Kerberos authentication. When I try to connect to one of the servers using [Net::SSH2](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH2), [`auth_list()`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2#auth_list-username-) returns `gssapi-keyex` and `gssapi-with-mic`. However, [`auth()`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2#auth-...-) doesn't support either.

Is there a Perl module that naively (e.g., without using Expect.pm) supports [GSSAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSSAPI) authentication over SSH?

Comment: I think you may be out of luck.  I don't think there's a Perl module that implements GSSAPI.  One could probably build one on top of Net::SSH2 and the GSSAPI module, but implementing the ssh protocol for GSSAPI is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this module a shot?

http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Authen::Negotiate

Or possibly this one as well...

http://metacpan.org/pod/Authen::Simple::Kerberos

Comment: These are authen for match_passwd, but no keep session for ssh